# [__NSCFBoolean value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a model in Objective-C with a variable as follows:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) id value;
```

Due to generic types, this variable can contain values of all sorts including NSString, NSNumber, and also Bool.

Now, for some reason, the following code:

```
[model.value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]];
```

crashes. The message in the crash is the what I mentioned in the title. This crash is rarely reproducible, but has resulted in a major amount of my users to face a crash (reported by Crashlytics).

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: The error says that `model` is BOOL and in ObjC BOOL is not an object.

Comment: @vadian are you sure this means the `model` is a BOOL, and not the `value`?

Comment: I'm quite sure.

Comment: @danialzahid94 In the debugger, what's the type of `model` and `value`? I suspect the correct code should be `[model isKindOfClass: NSNull.class]`

Comment: @Alexander I'm actually not able to capture this in the debugger. This is constantly reported by Crashlytics. Hence the uncertainty. But I understand your point. Will try it out.

Comment: It means that your model object is an instance of __NSCFBoolean class for some reason instead of your object class. __NSCFBoolean is one of the classes that back up NSNumber class cluster, so you should look in your code where you might assign model to a NSNumber instance especially to a boolean, e.g. model = @(YES). Probably serialization/deserialization went wrong somewhere

Comment: You should be showing us a lot more of the crash log.

Comment: @vadian `BOOL` is not an object, that's right, but `_NSCFBoolean` is absolutely not the same type as `BOOL`, and is actually an object. Simply the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to generic types, this variable can contain values of all sorts including NSString, NSNumber, and also Bool.

I don't know what you mean by "due to generic types". And I also don't know what you mean by Bool, which is not an Objective-C type; you might mean bool or Boolean or BOOL.

But it should be impossible to assign a boolean of *any* ilk to an `id` property, because an `id` is an object, and a boolean is a scalar. The only way I can think of that this might happen is if this is a non-ARC file; under ARC, the compiler will stop you.

So one possibility is that this is a non-ARC file and you are making a terrible mistake here by trying to treat an `id` as if it could hold a scalar.

However, let's leave that, because the error indicates that it is `model`, not its `value` property, that's the problem.

A more insidious possibility is that you have a threading / memory management issue and the `model` pointer has dangled, leaving you pointing at something else entirely. The fact that you can't reproduce this yourself is suggestive that that's the case; such issues are difficult to track down, especially when the crash is purely diagnostic of a problem that has already happened some time earlier.

Comment: You should also suggest to enable zombie objects to help diagnose this crash.

Comment: @Macmade Can't enable zombies on the customer's machine! If he can't reproduce it, he's not going to reproduce it with zombies.

Comment: Right, but worth a try IMHO. A `nil` value won't crash, and if he's testing with a debug build, memory won't be the same, and the crash might not occur for this reason.